# C# Queryable Order by , take and where not working right

Tags: c#

That is my code:

```
IQueryable<ICB_TRANSACTION> Query = DbContext.Set<ICB_TRANSACTION>();

if (_input.i_Type != -99) // -99 = All type
{
    Query = Query.Where(x => x.TYPE == _input.i_Type);
}
if (_input.i_Member_ID != null && _input.i_Member_ID > 0)
{
    Query = Query.Where(x => x.CREATE_BY_ID == _input.i_Member_ID);
}
if (_input.b_OderByDesc)
    Query = Query.OrderByDescending(x => x.ID);
else
    Query = Query.OrderBy(x => x.ID);

if (_input.i_Top > 0)
{
    Query = Query.Take(_input.i_Top);
}

return Query.ToList();
```

That is result:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q20UM.png)

But i want to like this: 
[Want to like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yk7j0.png)

how can i do that? Help me please!

Comment: Could you explain what's  `not working right` (which is sadly not self-explanatory) ? I may miss something, but I don't see any major difference - except the usage of a subquery - between the sql commands.

Comment: i have query i dont save that but when using 
"order by [table].ID desc" -> no row 
but change "desc to asc -> some record. 
Me and my colleague cant explain that. The sub query alway have rows

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I see something strange in your code, that's :

You have an `IQueryable<T>`.

You try to order by / take : but `OrderBy` / `OrderByDescending` return an `IOrderedQueryable<T>`, and you assign the result to your `IQueryable<T>`.

Even if `IOrderedQueryable<T>` inherits from `IQueryable<T>`, I guess this could lead to unexpected results.

I would do it like that

```
//filteredQuery is an IQueryable<ICB_TRANSACTION>
var filteredQuery = DbContext.Set<ICB_TRANSACTION>();

if (_input.i_Type != -99) // -99 = All type
    filteredQuery = filteredQuery.Where(x => x.TYPE == _input.i_Type);

if (_input.i_Member_ID != null && _input.i_Member_ID > 0)
    filteredQuery = filteredQuery.Where(x => x.CREATE_BY_ID == _input.i_Member_ID);

//now we have done the filters, let's do the order by / take part.
//sortedQuery is an IOrderedQueryable<ICB_TRANSACTION>
var sortedQuery = _input.b_OderByDesc 
     ? filteredQuery.OrderByDescending(x => x.ID)
     : filteredQuery.OrderBy(x => x.ID);

if (_input.i_Top > 0)
    sortedQuery = sortedQueryable .Take(_input.i_Top);

return sortedQuery.ToList();
```